# Is there a onSessionClose in WampServerProtocol?

Tags: python, autobahn

I'm using Autobahn Python to make a WAMP server.  I open up a database connection in `onSessionOpen` of my subclass of `WampServerProtocol`, and of course need to close it when the connection closed.  However, I can't find a session close handler in either the tutorials or the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WAMP specific session close (since WAMP does not have a closing handshake separate from WebSocket). You can use the `onClose` hook.

Another point you might have a look at: the recommended way of accessing databases from Twisted applications is via `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` which automatically manages a database connection pool on a background thread pool - independent of frontend protocol instances (like WAMP protocol instances).

Disclaimer: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: We're using SQLAlchemy as an ORM, and that has it's own connection pooling.  Unfortunately, I don't see a way to use `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` instead.

Comment: I see. I won't get into the decision to use an ORM in the first place, but like to point to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7041697/884770 and http://findingscience.com/twistar/